# set api environments variables in remote micro frontend Angular

Tags: angular, environment-variables, micro-frontend

I need to consume a remote micro frontend which is an Angular app, this app has its own services to call certain API, it has its own requests to a certain API. Also, that app has a config to set environment variables that contain the URL API. When I'm trying to consume from the main app (Angular as well) I don't know how to set those variables to avoid hard coding them directly to the remote micro frontend.  For example the remote app calls

> http://rutaapi/api/items

, where "**rutaapi/api**" is setted with env variables, but the resuult that I'm getting is

> https://items/

.
So I need to somehow provide that environment variable towards the remote micro frontend.

Additional info.: In the remote app, I'm setting the env variables using the **APP_INITIALIZER** provide in the AppModule. Maybe I have to use only one APP_INITIALIZER in the main app and not anymore in the remote app?
Any suggestions please.

Comment: probably going to need more code context, what's the APP_INITIALIZER look like currently?

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variables using a `config.json` in the `src` root.
You can follow the examples in [this guide](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/03/04/making-environment-variables-accessible-in-front-end-containers):

```
//config.json
{
  "ENV": "development",
  "BASE_URL": "http://localhost:3000"
}

//app.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import Config from "../config.json";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  environment = Config.ENV;
  baseUrl = Config.BASE_URL;
}
```

For the topic of multiple environments (1 per MFE) vs 1 for all -  check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755812/micro-front-env-config-in-react/72815704#72815704)

Let me know if this helps